# Windows Server 2016 H.264 Decoder

Tags: windows-server-2016, codecs, h.264

I have a Windows Server 2016 Remote Desktop Services Session Host with the Server Media Foundation feature and Firefox installed. When users try to watch YouTube videos they are unable to do so because it reports a H264 codec is not installed. What features are required for Firefox to be able to decode H264 video?

[image]

Comment: Does IE can play them ? I ask as I wonder if it's a codec issue or a firefox config's error.

Comment: This also happens in Server 2016 Desktop Experience, on the console. Probably doesn't have to do with remote desktop services.